# How can i reduce the spacing between checkboxes rendering in a django template?

Tags: django, checkbox, html-templates

I have retrived some data by retreival from database and saved in into variable DATA
`

```
def sendApproval(request):
    form = SendApp
    data = Profile.objects.filter(Admin="Lavanya")
    context = { "form": form,"data":data}
    return render(request, 'homePageHtml/SendApproval.html', context)
```

`
And then in the html templete I used that data to represent it as checkboxes

`

```
{%for a in data%}<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="recommender" name="choosen" value="{{a.UserName}}" >
  <label for="recommender" style="font-size:15px"> {{a.UserName}}</label><br><br>
{%endfor%}
```

`

and after viewing it on web page it is visible like this:
[image: I wanted to reduce the gap between these checkboxes]

Any one with the solution will be appreciated! Thanks in advance

I tried:

`

```
.adjust-line-height {
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

`
adding this into my code, but this didn't work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you can reduce the < br > amount in the HTML part, something like:

```
{%for a in data%}<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="recommender" name="choosen" value="{{a.UserName}}" >
<label for="recommender" style="font-size:15px"> {{a.UserName}}</label><br>
{%endfor%}
```